# In Asp.Net ajax controls?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net ajax, is there any control that indicate the user, wait processing is going on ?.
i have to display any animation.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Thread.Sleep(1500);


    string sqr = "select * from Pra_Region";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqr, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    grdProduct.Visible = true;
    grdProduct.DataSource = ds;
    grdProduct.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UpdateProgress` control to achieve this. You can show anything inside the `UpdateProgess` container when any `AJAX postback` occurs. Look at the example below:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        tt.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        grid.DataSource = new List<object>
                              {
                                  new {Name = "Munim", Age = 2, Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()},
                                  new {Name = "Rashim", Age = 3, Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()},
                                  new {Name = "Robin", Age = 25, Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}
                              };
        grid.DataBind();
    }
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdPnl1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="grid"></asp:DataGrid>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="click" />
            <div id="tt" runat="server">
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updQuoteProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdPnl1"
        DisplayAfter="0">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Loading...</ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</div>
</form>
```

Use the table in your `DataSet`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Thread.Sleep(1500);


    string sqr = "select * from Pra_Region";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqr, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    grdProduct.Visible = true;
    grdProduct.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    grdProduct.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: When i bind a data to gridview it is not showing the gridview. i write code to bind the datba to gridview in button click event. it is not showing gridview.

Comment: @Suryasasidhar did you try to call `dataGrid.DataBind()`? I have updated the code above. Please take a look